# post_content with line breaks

Tags: the-content, post-content

I want to be able to get post_content with line breaks. What is the best way to do it?

I previously use the_content() which was working fine until I needed to install a plugin that adds share buttons on each post.

Since then the output of my the_content includes texts from the share buttons.

I tried to use post_contents which contains the correct content I need to output on my template file but the problem is the line breaks were stripped off.

Is it possible to get post_content with line breaks preserved?

Thanks

Comment: This is the wrong approach. If there's something _wrong_ with a plugin, try to fix that, instead of leaving it be and work on some other things. Since the plugin injects content via a filter function, you just need to remove that function.

Comment: @tf Thanks for your comment. Is it possible to remove the function just to get the correct the_content but keep it working? The thing is, I have a single post page that is OK to have the plugin's like buttons. What I'd like to do is to offer a full screen view of the same post. This is where I do not need the share buttons. Other than the full screen view, I need the plugin to show the buttons. Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
$getPost = get_the_content();
$postwithbreaks = wpautop( $getPost, true/false );
echo $postwithbreaks;
```

The second argument in wpautop can be up to you whether it's true of false, see the link below. It is described as follows:

> (bool) (Optional) If set, this will convert all remaining line breaks after paragraphing. Line breaks within <script>, <style>, and <svg> tags are not affected.
>
> Default value: true

Source:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/

Comment: thanks! It works. Sorry I cant vote up yet. Need more reputations

Comment: Thank you so much man . works like a charm.